# C++ old version (not c++11 )-- map -> override hash code

Tags: c++, hashcode

I am a java guy.. learning c++. I am trying to use map in c++ using `std::map`. Somehow I also need to override its hash code and equals method. I can do this in c++11 using `unordered_map` but how can i do this in old version. I know in `std::map`,  the third parameter is `operator<` but not hashcode (like in `unordered_map`). I also know that `std::map` (a ordered map) is in fact a TreeMap (Red black tree). But How can i do, which i want to do, using this data structure or some other in older c++ version.

Comment: If you are using an old version of visual studio you can use the non-standard [stdext::hash_map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x7w9f6z(v=vs.100).aspx). But the real answer should be that if you're learning and dont have any requirements to use an older compiler why dont you just get a recent tool set which includes c++11?

Comment: You'll probably have to go for [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/unordered.html).

Comment: I know about hash_map but since I can't use it because its not part of Standard library

Comment: If you cant use things outside of the standard library then the fact is older versions of c++ dont have a hash_map equivalent.

Comment: Well, there's no hash table in old C++, so that's it. What exactly do you need it for?

Comment: i am porting a java code in c++ and to keep code same at some extend, I am thinking to use some similar data structure. If its not possible, I will go for some another option

Comment: *Why* do you need to override the hash code and equals, if they aren't used by `std::map`? What purpose would it serve?

Comment: If you are migrating from Java to C++, and consequently don't have a mass of old C++ code that you need to stay backwards-compatible with, then why the heck would you reject C++11? It's universally hailed as **precisely** what the doctor ordered.

Answer (score 5):

As you noted, std::map is similar to Java's TreeMap. Overriding the hash code for TreeMap in Java is not useful, as it will not be used by the collection. Instead TreeMap takes an (optional) additional argument: The comparator.

std::map does pretty much the same thing but instead of a runtime parameter, it has a compile time template argument:

```
template <class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key> [...]>
class map;
```

As you can see, this defaults to std::less. This can be overriden in two different ways:

- Either define a new std::less for your key type by selective specialization. This will be used globally within its scope, or
- supply a custom Comparer struct when declaring your map

**Version 1:**

```
 template<>
 struct std::less<Key> {
   bool operator()(const &Key lhs, const Key &rhs) const
   {
      // compare lhs with rhs
   }
 };
```

**Version 2:**

```
 struct CompareKeys {
   bool operator()(const &Key lhs, const Key &rhs) const
   {
      // compare lhs with rhs
   }
 };

 std::map<Key, Value, CompareKeys> my_map;
```

C++14 and up change the declarations slightly but the mechanism more or less stays the same.

Comment: Version 3: Overload `bool operator<(const Key&, const Key&);`

Comment: But don't because that pollutes everything else.